# Update REST query based to get items from List in SP 2013

Tags: rest, custom-list

I have a query in REST API which is :

```
var i = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><BeginsWith><Fieldref Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>Content type value here</Value></BeginsWith><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='FieldNameHere' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='SomeFieldName' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value><Eq></And></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='SomeField' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query></View>"}"
```

As you can see this is a POST call and not a GET call. I need to change this to a GET call since POST is giving me permission related issues, in that the above query will only work for people with Contribute and above level permissions. It won't work for People with Read Access.

One option I thought would be to use the "items" API query but I'm not sure how I can pass the above Caml Query to it

```
var i = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?CamlQueryConditionhere?$select=Fields.."
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The POST itself should not cause permission related issues. Are you getting a 403 back from the request? There's probably another reason why you're getting access denied.

The CamlQuery method is not supported over GET - to do a GET you'll need to use the OData operators. You should be able to AND two conditions to achieve what you're looking for.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests